# Tmux changes to default preinstalled nano version instead of newly installed homebrew one

Tags: terminal, tmux, macos, nano, homebrew

When i use nano in the terminal without enabling tmux, it shows the path for the brew version `nano is an alias for /opt/homebrew/Cellar/nano`

However when i use tmux, `type nano` shows the same path but when nano is actually used it opens the preinstalled system version `2.0.6`. I'm not sure if that's an error in my tmux config or nano.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `echo $PATH` before you open `tmux`, and compare it to your `PATH` from inside `tmux`, you'll notice that they're different. The default behavior of `tmux` is to launch new shells as a login shell.

Login shells on MacOS run a utility called `path_helper` found in `/etc/profile`. The default `PATH` on a clean installation of MacOS is something like

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

`path_helper` prepends this string to your `PATH`. So when you run `nano`, the older version is found first in this new `PATH`.

The fix for this annoying consequence is answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/544989/does-tmux-sort-the-path-variable) by [Graham Ashton](https://superuser.com/users/194228/graham-ashton) -

Empty your `PATH` before `path_helper` is executed by adding the following to `~/.bash_profile`

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    PATH=""
    source /etc/profile
fi
```

Make sure to upvote Graham's answer if this solves your problem.